# Univariate random variables with a multiparameter exponential family

Tags: posterior, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

I have this expression of a posterior distribution:

$$h(\Delta|z_1,\ldots,z_m)=\exp\left\{\frac{(z_1,\ldots,z_m)^T(\Delta,\ldots,\Delta)}{2}+\frac{(z_1,\ldots,z_m)^T(z_1,\ldots,z_m)}{4}-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\psi(z_j)\right\}\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{m}{2}} \exp\left(-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m}\Delta^2}{4}\right)h(\Delta)$$

$h(\Delta)$ is the prior of $\Delta$ and $\psi(\cdot)$ is some function you don't have to care about it.

Here $\Delta$ is the variable, and $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_m)$ are my parmeters which are given. But of course as you can notice $\Delta$ is not a vector. On the RHS of the formula I had to repeat $\Delta$ $m$ times so I can represent the expression $\Delta\sum_{j=1}^{m}z_j$ as a vector multiplication $(z_1,\ldots,z_m)^T(\Delta,\ldots,\Delta)$. With that expression above I identify the exponential family of the form.
$$P(\Delta|z_1,\ldots,z_m)=h(\Delta)e^{\eta(z_1,\ldots,z_m)^T(T(\Delta),\ldots,T(\Delta))-B(z_1,\ldots,z_m)}$$

Where
$$\eta(z_1,\ldots,z_m)=(z_1,\ldots,z_m)/2$$ is the natural parameter of this family.
$$(T(\Delta),\ldots,T(\Delta))=(\Delta,\cdots,\Delta)$$ is the sufficient statistic.
$$B(z_1,\ldots,z_m)=-\frac{(z_1,\ldots,z_m)^T(z_1,\ldots,z_m)}{4}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\psi(z_j)$$ is the normalising factor of this family.

The strange thing is I get an artificial representation of the sufficient statistic, $(T(\Delta),\ldots,T(\Delta))=(\Delta,\cdots,\Delta)$. These are just copies of $\Delta$. Can someone advise me on what to do?

I would like to know if there is an identification problem with such a representation.

Comment: Thanks for citing that out. Nope this is not a class assignment it is my own going research.

Comment: The first formula contains (a) twice the sum on $j$ and (b) unnecessary terms, i.e. parts in the exponential that do not depend on $\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion in the question between what is a parameter and what is an observation. If you have a posterior on $\Delta$, this means $\Delta$ is the parameter and the $z_i$'s are the observations.

Since what I understand to be the likelihood part factorises as$$\exp\left\{ \Delta\times\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^m z_i+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=1}^m z_i-\sum_{j=1}^m \psi(z_i)\right\}\times\exp\left\{-\frac{m}{4}\Delta^2\right\}$$this is a one-parameter exponential family with sufficient statistic $$T(z_1,\ldots,z_m)=\sum_{j=1}^m z_i\,.$$And the normalising constant is$$\exp\left\{-\frac{m}{4}\Delta^2\right\}$$a function of $\Delta$, not of the $z_i$'s. What you write as $B(\mathbf{z})$ is part of the dominating measure in $\mathcal{Z}$, the sample space.

Comment: Thanks very much @Xi'an the parameters are really $z_1,\ldots,z_m$. It is a posterior and not a likelihood, so indeed the parameters are the $z$s. That is the source of difficulty.